# "geolocation can be unsafe" eslint scan-js rule

Tags: javascript

I played with [Eslint](http://eslint.org/) and [eslint-scanjs](https://github.com/mozfreddyb/eslint-config-scanjs) security plugin and came across the check 'property_geolocation'. The source code of the check is:

```
"use strict";

module.exports = function (context) {

  return {
    "MemberExpression": function (node) {
      if (node.property.name == 'geolocation') {
        context.report(node, "geolocation can be unsafe");

      }
    }
  }
}
```

so it gives no clue about why it's dangerous to use the property. Can anyone explain what risks of using the 'geolocation' property and how it can be abused?

Comment: Research the commit logs of this rule and maybe ask on their issue tracker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation) and [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=geolocation), some browsers will allow geolocation to be served over HTTP, in which case the usual risks of a MITM apply.

This is a guess on my part, but if an attacker can uncover your physical location, they could exploit it in any of the following ways:

- Find your home/work addresses, and use that for any of the following:

  - knowing when it's safer to break in or when's the best time to swat you.
  - framing you for possessing illicit material ([as (nearly) happened](https://krebsonsecurity.com/2016/01/guy-who-tried-to-frame-me-in-heroin-plot-pleads-guilty-to-cybercrime-charges/) to Brian Krebs).
  - covering their tracks.
- Use it to create more targeted phishing attempts (we know that Pilib Uí Rólaun regularly goes to Bank A on the main street of Ballycac - so, he's more likely to fall for a request to log into this than for Bank B).
- Sell it to a third party that might find it useful (for any of the above reasons).